# Python 2.7 read exported variables from bash

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a python2.7 script which is calling a bash script, inside the bash script i'm exporting 2 variable i've tried with `declare -x` and with `export`, then i'm trying to read this variables in the python script using `os.getenv` and i also tried using `os.environ` but i'm getting  a `None`type each time.
Here is a snippet from my scripts:

Python:

```
def set_perforce_workspace():
        global workspace_path
        global workspace_root_path
        script_path = "somePath"
        depot_name = "TestingTools"
        dir_to_download = "vtf"
        bash_command = "./createWorkspace.sh " + "-d " + depot_name + " -w " \
                       + PerforceUtils.WORKSPACE_NAME + " -a " + dir_to_download
        print bash_command
        print os.getcwd()
        try:
            os.chdir(script_path)
        except OSError as e:
            print "Error: {0}".format(e)
        print os.getcwd()
        return_code = call([bash_command], shell=True)
        test = os.getenv("workspace_path")
        print "this is test {0}".format(test)
        workspace_path = os.getenv("workspace_path")
        workspace_root_path = os.getenv("workspace_root_path")
        print "This is the return code {0}".format(return_code)
        print "this is the workspace path: {0}".format(workspace_path)
        print "this is the workspace root path: {0}".format(workspace_root_path)
        return return_code
```

Bash:

```
declare -x workspace_root_path="$workspaceProjPath"
export workspace_path="$workspaceProjPathLocal"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ):

> This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported, typically during Python startup as part of processing site.py. Changes to the environment made after this time are not reflected in os.environ, except for changes made by modifying os.environ directly.

So basically when your bash script changes the environment and then goes back to your python script the environment variables aren't refreshed. Pretty annoying. As the docs say the best solution is to add your variables to the environ list directly, like:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = '/bin/'
```

How you accomplish this is up to you, piping is a pretty decent way to do it. Albeit annoying. Unfortunately there is no way to "refresh" the environment list. In a lot of situations it might be best just to drop your bash script and somehow adapt it to the python script.

Comment: I didn't understand the `os.environ['PATH'] = '/bin/'` part, and is there any thing that i can do, i really need to get those variables..

Comment: `os.environ` is just a list. You can add members (i.e.) new environment variables just by assigning a new index to a value. So for you: `os.environ["workspace_path"] = "$workspaceProjPathLocal"`. To get this *from* the bash script and not just do it in Python you'll actually have to pipe the environment varibles from the bash script to python using `popen` there are lots of good examples out there to google.